# Apple TestFlight error 'Couldn't accept the invite'

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

I have installed an app successfully as an internal tester. Now the app is ready for external testing, and has passed Apple review. In the email received from Apple, I clicked the `Open in TestFlight` button, which opened the TestFlight app and displayed the app details.

Clicking the `INSTALL` button fails with the following alert:

> **Couldn't accept the invite**
>
> You've already accepted the invite for this app.
>
> OK

The message does identify the problem. Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Comment: My own answer helped my scenario.

Answer (score 38):

Also make sure that you're not trying to install as internal tester while being added as an external tester in a previous build because this will for sure result in the same error. To resolve this problem simply log in to iTunes Connect and remove this account from the external testers list - then you should be able to install as internal tester without problem.

Comment: this undoubtably saved me hours of troubleshooting. Cheers to you Ural

Comment: Thanks Ural, that was my case.

Comment: This saved me after struggling for 4 hours. Thanks!

Comment: Still not working for me. Removed the external tester, added as internal. Still getting the same message. itc is the worst.

Answer (score 16):

I fixed this by unsubscribing to the old version of the app and then accepting the invite.

Comment: How did you 'unsubscribed' to the old version ?

Answer (score 15):

I got the same message. In the TestFlight app I had the previous version of the same app with the 'Expired' status. I clicked on that expired version and on the detail view scrolled to the bottom and **tapped on "Stop testing"**. After this, I was able to accept the most recent invitation.

Answer (score 6):

You can only be associated with an app as either an internal or external tester. You cannot be both at the same time.

You will need to unsubscribe from one of them, if you wish to be part of another.

Same thing applies if you need to send out another email invite. Remove from beta testing, then add to beta testing.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new answer.

It is possible for an invitation to be sent to an email address and accepted with a different email address. This is only likely to happen if you use two different Apple IDs

An invitation was sent to my work email not associated with my Apple ID. I opened the email from my iPhone and accepted the invitation with my personal Apple ID. Months later, I received another invitation. I opened the invitation on an iPad where I was signed in using my work email address. The error message above was displayed.

Fix the problem by signing into the device with the same Apple ID you used to originally accept the invite.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the user from the External testing, All Testers, and Internal Testing and re-doing everything but still had the issue. I then realized that I had public links enabled way back and I think I used one of them with that Apple ID, after proceeding to remove all public links from All Testers" I was able to re-accept the invite from the Internal Testing group.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that the invitation was sent to an email address that was not the apple id of the tester. An invitation to the apple id of the tester worked.

The "stop testing" tip also worked when I tested on myself, however it was not possible for the tester to get to the "stop testing" button.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by eliminating a duplicate email address from the All Testers list, keeping the one that had already downloaded a previous version of the app.  This solved the problem for me even though the email address that was deleted was not the address that was trying to respond to the invitation.